# Does the shield of faith spell combine with the mirror image spell to provide an AC boost to the illusory duplicates from mirror image?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, cleric, sorcerer

This is a spell synergy question.

Casting order is *mirror image* spell first so the illusory duplicates AC are set, and then casting *shield of faith spell*, creating a barrier "around" the creature mirror image was cast on and if I am right around the occupied space of said creature, so this would include the illusory duplicates.

Shield of Faith states:

> A shimmering field appears and surrounds a creature of your choice within range, granting it a +2 bonus to AC for the duration.

Mirror Image states:

> Three illusory duplicates of yourself appear in your space. Until the spell ends, the duplicates move with you and mimic your actions, shifting position so it's impossible to track which image is real. You can use your action to dismiss the illusory duplicates.

Would the "shield of faith" spell provide an AC boost to the illusory duplicates created via the "mirror image" spell given that they are all occupying the same space and moving in sync (mimicing your actions).

If this is indeed how these 2 spells sync, the illusory duplicates would instead have 15 AC each instead of 13 AC (base creature has a dex bonus of +3)
while also boosting the original creature's AC by +2.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Is it possible to increase the AC of a mirror image duplicate?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135926/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-ac-of-a-mirror-image-duplicate)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 19):

#### *Shield of Faith* boosts your AC only.

*Shield of Faith* says:

> A shimmering field appears and surrounds a creature of your choice within range, granting it a +2 bonus to AC for the duration.

Only the chosen creature receives a bonus to AC. It is not an area of effect.

#### *Mirror Image* duplicates do not use your AC for anything.

*Mirror image* states:

> A duplicate's AC equals 10 + your Dexterity modifier.

This does not respect your own armor class at all, so changing your armor class with *shield of faith* does nothing to the *mirror image* duplicates.

Comment: As a matter of clarification, would the duplicates look shimmering? or would that shimmering field give you away to a close observer?

Comment: @Mathaddict Up to the DM, but I'd make the duplicates appear shimmering as well. There's no reason to nerf mirror image like that.